# Script for a requests to URL

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make a custom script that will send a request to the page and test it for availability, if the answer is 200, then I want the answer to be 1, if any other 2, and the metric will not be recorded, tell me how best to do it?
Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm just learning python

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning 
import os
import datetime
import pytz

def get_status_ghe():
    url_list = [os.environ.get('http://testurl.com:8080')]
    for i in range(0, len(url_list)):
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            print('ghe0')
        elif resp.status_code != 200:
            print('ghe1')
        else:
            print('ghe2')  
def ghe_request():
    try:
        resp = requests.head('http://testurl.com:8080')
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            return 1
            print(resp)
            print('1')
        else:
            return 0
            print(resp)
            print('0')
    except:
        return 0
```

Comment: The `for` loop is missing the call to `requests.head`.

Comment: None of the `print()` calls after `return` will execute, since `return` exits the function. Move `return` after the print statements.

Comment: Is `http://testurl.com:8080` really the name of your environment variable? It looks more like the value.

Comment: Either the status code is equal to 200 or it's not equal to 200. What's the other possibilities that you think would trigger `ghe2`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `requests.head()` in the loop.

Your second condition should just test for any `2xx` value (I assume that's what you mean by "any 2"). Then the `else:` block will handle all other status codes.

Don't use `for i in range(len(url_list)):` when you can more simply use `for url in url_list:`

```
def get_status_ghe():
    url_list = [os.environ.get('http://testurl.com:8080')]
    for url in url_list:
        resp = requests.head(url)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            print('ghe0')
        elif 201 <= resp.status_code <= 299:
            print('ghe1')
        else:
            print('ghe2')
```